# Проблема удаления внешнего ключа а также просмотр наличия его

Tags: sql, oracle, key, foreign-key

[image]

Требует keyword, не знаю почему. Также не хочет выводить foreign key

Comment: Судя по сообщениям об ошибках это у вас oracle. (это стоило указать в вопросе и в тегах). А в oracle ключи удаляются совершенно иначе https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/drop.php  И никакого SHOW в нем нет. Там есть https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tools/rtoolsijcomrefdescribe.html  Изучайте документацию именно на свою БД, команды в каждой БД свои и документация mysql совершенно не годится для оракла

Comment: Не только в oracle drop constraint

Comment: По-моему удаление fk именно выражением drop constraint вообще часть стандарта SQL

Comment: @Komdosh только не в mysql, документацией на который явно пользовался ТС

Comment: @Мелкий Да кто же стандарты то соблюдает, особенно в MySQL ... https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-drop-constraint-in-mysql.html  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Пока комментаторы не перессорились, следует закрыть вопрос, во избежание... Alex Smith, укажите используемую СУБД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо дропать `constraint`

```
ALTER TABLE work DROP CONSTRAINT ArtistFk
```

Comment: а как посмотреть все ключи связанные с этой таблицей? Не могу таблицу дропнуть - выдает unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys

Comment: @AlexSmith - не спрашивайте в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос. Или задайте новый (создайте новую тему). А главное, укажите, какую именно СУБД используете.

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб удалить ключ таблицы выполняем команду:

```
ALTER TABLE имя_таблицы DROP CONSTRAINT имя_ключа;
```

Чтоб посмотреть список первичных и внешних ключей в таблицы можно через следующие запросы:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'имя_таблицы'
    AND CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
        FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
        WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN('P', 'R'));
```

а если же есть стандартное обозначение первичных ключей и внешних ключей в системе, то:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'имя_таблицы'
    AND (CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK%' 
    OR CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK%');
```